# Go environment variables stay unchanged after setting

Tags: go

I start learning Go programming by watching online tutorials. I use Windows command prompt. However, after I typed `set GOOS = darwin` then used `go env` to print environment variables, `GOOS` was not set to `GOOS=darwin` but still `GOOS=windows` as default.

---

Here is what I got. Could someone tell me where I went wrong such that I cannot make change on `GOOS`?

```
C:\GoPath\src\palindrome>set GOOS = darwin

C:\GoPath\src\palindrome>go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
```

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the text into your question rather than linking to a screenshot.

Comment: It probably has to do with the behavior of the Windows `set` command. When I do something similar on Linux it does affect the output of `go env` as expected. I'll let someone who's more familiar with Windows provide more information. And I'm not 100% clear on the relationship between environment variables and the output of `go env`; the man page is not terribly illuminating.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Thompson, I have edited it but not sure if it looks proper now. I am not sure how to format commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Any extra spaces around either the variable name or the string, will not be ignored, SET is not forgiving of extra spaces like many other scripting languages."

Change `set GOOS = darwin` to `set GOOS=darwin` - i.e., the same format you see in the output of `go env`.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your answer I am so grateful, if not you I may make this mistake many times before I  figure it out.